# Error importing packages into Torch

Tags: bash, lua, torch

I just installed Torch7 [as per the instructions](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html). However, I am unable to port any packages via the command-line interpreter:

```
kamransiquisMBP:~ khsiddiqui$ th

  ______             __   |  Torch7                                         
 /_  __/__  ________/ /   |  Scientific computing for Lua. 
  / / / _ \/ __/ __/ _ \  |  Type ? for help                                
 /_/  \___/_/  \__/_//_/  |  https://github.com/torch         
                          |  http://torch.ch                  

    th> require "nn"
    ...rs/khsiddiqui/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384:
    ...rs/khsiddiqui/orch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384:
    loop or previous error loading module 'torch'
    stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error 
        ...rs/khsiddiqui/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: 
        in function 'require' [string "_RESULT={require "nn"}"]:1: in main chunk   
        [C]: in function 'xpcall' 
        ...rs/khsiddiqui/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651:
        in function 'real'...iqui/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199:
        in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x010fc1cd00    
    th> 1 + 1
    2
```

Outside of the interpreter, (just from the command line)  I ran the command `luarocks install nn`, but the same error described above persisted.

Would love to get Torch7 up and running!

---

Hi, @deltheil ...

```
kamransiquisMBP:~ khsiddiqui$ luajit -ltorch
luajit: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:11: cannot load
 '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libtorch.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:11: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x010a587dd0
    [C]: at 0x010a50bd00
```

Running the following after `luajit`...

```
th> ok, err = pcall(require, 'libtorch')
th> print(ok, err)
false   error loading module 'lib torch' from file     
'/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libtorch.so':
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libtorch.so,
 6): Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/khsiddiqui/torch/install/lib/libTH.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `luajit -ltorch`

Comment: i updated the q ... i appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Hmm... you should then double check the outputs (logs) of `./install.sh` (the main install script from the official getting started guide). What do you obtain if you do `luajit` then `ok, err = pcall(require, 'libtorch')` and `print(ok, err)`?

Comment: Also: it is strange it looks under `/usr/local/lib`. If you followed the official guidelines, then torch installs all libraries and bins under your home folder (`~/torch/install`). Did you answered yes to [this](https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/cbb5161/install.sh#L178-L179)? Did you work with a former system wide Lua / LuaJIT install (e.g. via Homebrew)?

Comment: You should have a look at this thread: https://github.com/torch/trepl/issues/37

Comment: thanks for the link. i use anaconda, and I also have enthought installed....

Comment: Thank you! nn can now be called .  I had to remove `./pkg/torch/lib/TH/cmake/FindMKL.cmake` first. I then ran `./clean.sh; ./install.sh` and it worked!!

Comment: You should definitely post an answer below so that it helps others in the future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks be to @deltheil for the assistance!

[As per the instructions on this page](https://github.com/torch/trepl/issues/37), what worked for me (on Mac OSX) was:

1. Locating and removing the file `./pkg/torch/lib/TH/cmake/FindMKL.cmake` ...
2. Doing a clean install by running `./clean.sh; ./install.sh` ...

After that Torch is running as intended :-). I am machine learning as we speak!